# Active window in R

Tags: r, user-interface, focus, tk-toolkit

I have a problem with R in Microsoft Windows.

When I run a script from 'R console' (Rgui) with `source('script_file')`, and my script creates a graphic device, I use `bringToTop()` to switch the focus between the two windows:

```
dev.new() # create the graphic device window, and this new window takes the focus
 ...
bringToTop(-1) # give back the focus to the 'R console' window
 ...
bringToTop(2) # give the focus to the graphic device window
```

When my R script creates a GUI window by means of the *tcltk2* library, I am not able to make the GUI window focused: the 'R console' is still the active window, and I must click on the GUI window to activate it.

```
library(tcltk2)
 ...
win1 <- tktoplevel()
tktitle(win1) <- "GUI window"
tkwm.geometry(win1, '300x200+100+100')
```

Please note that, if the previous script runs in Linux, the TK toplevel window takes the focus.

When I load 'R Commander' from 'R console':

```
library(Rcmdr)
```

the 'R Commander' GUI becomes the active window. I suppose that the 'R Commander' GUI uses the *tcltk2* library: how can the 'R Commander' window steal the focus from the 'R console'?

Comment: Can you provide sample code. Also, you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are aware that, in general, you're totally at the mercy of the OS for what is actually on top and receiving keystrokes? It's largely up to the user what main window gets the focus, not the application, though there are ways to add hints. (You need someone who knows the `tcltk2` library, which is quite distinct from Tcl and so out of my expertise.)

Comment: Mathieu, I edited the text and provided a sample code: does it help?

Comment: Donal, I know that the OS affects the result. I tried with `tkfocus()` and `tkraised()`, but without success. With `tcl("wm", "attributes", base, topmost=TRUE)`, I have the GUI window always on top, but it is not focused: I have to click on it to activate. Since Rcommander does the job, I would like to do the same trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is not elegant, but it works:

```
info_sys <- Sys.info()

if (info_sys['sysname'] == 'Windows') {
 shell("powershell -command [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') ; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('GUI window') ")
}
```